# Go router - flutter web login redirect issue

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter web application, I have login authentication mechanism placed to redirect the user to desired place after successful authentication.

User -> authenticated -> HomePage.dart

User -> not authenticated -> LoginPage.dart

On the above scenario, The user can able to go backward and see the login page. But the intended action is once the user logged in, he/she cannot go back to the login page until they log out!.

Here is the sample code from the main redirect:

```
redirect: (context, state) {
  final auth = bloc.state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated;
  var userRole = false;
   

  /// current location
  final locationClick = state.location;
 // debugPrint(auth.toString() + locationClick);

  if (auth && !userRole && (locationClick == '/$loginURLPagePath' || locationClick == 
  welcomeURLPagePath)) {
    return homeURLPagePath;
  } else if (auth && userRole && (locationClick == '/$loginURLPagePath' || 
   locationClick == welcomeURLPagePath)) {
    return adminhomeURLPagePath; //adminFeeSetupPath; // communicationPath;// 
   schoolSetupPath; //adminhomeURLPagePath; //; //classWisePaymentPath; 
  } else if (!auth) {
    return loginURLPagePath;
  }
  return null;
},
```

Though the code works good, but the redirection is horribly hard to understand without proper document from go-router flutter team.

Please suggest how to erase the stack after successful login.